# Snapshot isolation transaction failed

Tags: sql-server

Very often, when I execute a query on a SQL Server database, I receive this error:

> Snapshot isolation transaction failed in
> database 'DB' because the object accessed by the statement has
> been modified by a DDL statement in another concurrent transaction
> since the start of this transaction.  It is disallowed because the
> metadata is not versioned. A concurrent update to metadata can lead to
> inconsistency if mixed with snapshot isolation.

It's not a transaction, just a plain SELECT statement, so why should it conflict with an update in SNAPSHOT isolation level? Should I set the isolation level to READ COMMITTED before executing every query?

Comment: Every statement implicitly happens in its own transaction if you don't start one. The database likely has `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` activated so every `SELECT` also has a chance to fail. If, however, you get this "very often", it suggests someone has made a bad design choice somewhere: a table's metadata really isn't *supposed* to change "very often" in the first place, and where this can be expected to be the case, using snapshot isolation is probably not the best choice. You can override this with the `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` hint, but that really shouldn't be necessary on every query.

Comment: The error message says a DDL. conflict . Are you querying meta-data (e.g. catalog views) during DDL changes?

Comment: Mmm, I'm querying views, but are they considered metadata?

Comment: If you're querying a view, then both the definitions of the view and the underlying objects accessed by the view are in play, as in, if either the base objects or the views are modified, the query might fail. Views themselves are not metadata.

Comment: I added SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED before my query and I still get the error...

Comment: Does the database have `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` enabled? This automatically promotes every committed transaction to snapshot isolation. Per my comment, the only way to explicitly override that is the `READCOMMITTEDLOCK` hint on individual tables (there is no transaction isolation level that corresponds to this).

Comment: I've made a query on sys.databases and no table has the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT enabled... That's strange, unless the change has been done recently.